# read line with different length backwards c++

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I have a text file that I need to read data from, and these data will go into various arrays later. The text file looks like:

```
 1 5.154600E-05 1.329887E-02 1.907202E-03   3      -1    8937    8889       1       0     890    1532    1533
 2 4.639140E-03 9.845286E-03 1.659781E-02   1    9708       0       0    1617
 3 1.329887E-02 1.329887E-02 1.108239E-02   4    8497    5442       0    5711       0       1    1611    1619     889    1618
 4 1.030920E-04 5.154600E-05 1.412360E-02   3      -1    6966    6965       1       0     888    1620    1330
 5 6.030882E-03 6.546342E-03 1.030920E-04   2    8238    6002       0       0    1622    1621
 6 9.484464E-03 5.154600E-05 4.072134E-03   2    6104    5455       0       0    2481    1112
```

1st, I need to take out specific column (in this case 5th column). The size of lines are not equal, and I couldn't break reading after catching 5th column. cin.ignore didn't help.

2nd, 5th column is always an integer, say N, and then (maybe in a separate function) I need to read the LAST N number of same line and store them into arrays. I have no clue how to do it.

Here is part of code:

```
while (!myfile.eof())

  {
//     myfile.ignore (50, '\n'); // This is just a try. 5th col. always ends at 50th charachter of line. It didn't work!
    double a,b,c,d,e;

    myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;

    if (minsize>e)
      minsize=e;
    if (maxsize<e)
      maxsize=e;

    frequency2[int(e)]++;
  }
```

Any help ?

Comment: all lines have at least 11 columns so why don't just read the whole line and extract the 5th column because they're always at a specific index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `std::getline` to get the whole line  in each iteration, and then use `std::istringstream` to parse out the columns. Something like this:

```
std::string buffer;
std::getline(myfile, buffer);
std::istringstream iss(buffer);

// Do your stuff
double a, b, c, d, e;
iss >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomming you using a string with some reversed size like 60 bytes.
Then read char by char. If the char is a **White space/Line break** and the **string size > 0** you should **handle** the data in the string and clear the data in the string. If the **size == 0** you should **continue**.

```
void handle(std::string& data)
{
    if(data.size())
    {
        //Handle Input
        data.clear();
    }
}

std::string buf(60);
while(file.isgood())
{
    char c = file.get();
    if(!file.isgood())
        break;

    switch(c)
    {
        case '\n':
        case ' '://Probably you need more cases here just debug to find out
        handle(buf); 
        break;      
        default:
        buf.push_back(c);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete others solutions:

- getline is the good way to read a file line by line
- you could use (boost) tokenizer to build an iterable from the line
- you could use (boost) lexical cast to parse data from this iterable

something like

```
while(file.good())
{
    string line;
    getline(file, line);

    if(line.empty())
        continue;

    boost::tokenizer<> tok(line);
    boost::tokenizer<>::iterator tokiter = tok.begin();

    double ex1  = boost::lexical_cast<double>(*tokiter);
    tokiter++;
    float ex2  = boost::lexical_cast<float>(*tokiter);
    //etc..
    cout << ex1 << " " << ex2 << endl;
}
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html